# Is this sentence correct? I hereby declare my parental consent for the planned marriage

Tags: grammar

I hereby declare my parental consent for the planned marriage

Comment: Technically, yes. It is kind of awkward, though.

Comment: Correct in what sense? What is the context?

Comment: @Ricky I think it's clumsy because it is mixing two concepts. I would say that it should be "give ... consent to": we normally "give consent to" but "express our support for" a course of action

Answer (score 0):

It is ‘correct’ but it sounds a bit too formal - like you are launching a boat or opening a shop!

I think you need softer, less formal words for a family occasion.

Such as ‘I am delighted to give my consent to the marriage’. Or wouldn’t ‘we are’ be better? As presumably both parents are consenting.

You do not need to say ‘parental consent’.  Presumably, everyone lnows you are the parent! So that comes across a bit clumsy and overbearing (a bit like, the policeman standing there in uniform, saying ‘I am the policeman here’!)

You don’t need the word ‘planned’ either - as you are consenting to the marriage - not the plan of it.

In my ideal world, children are free to marry who they want, without needing consent. And parents express their delight or, if less than delighted, quietly keep their opinion to themselves.